# How can I create a project in JIRA using REST API call in SPRING MVC application?

Tags: java, api, rest, project, jira

I need to use basic authorization and then create a project in JIRA via REST API call. I can't clearly get from the following [URL](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/project-createProject)

I need a working example for this.

Comment: You need to show people what you have tried and ask a specific question. ie. why you are getting an error, or why it's throwing an error, etc.

Comment: That URL is simply saying that you can submit a HTTP POST request with `JSON` in that format to create a project . To submit a REST request, you might use a browser plugin like `RESTClient` for Firefox etc but it seems you are writing your own client in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a REST API, you can use RestTemplate, which is a Spring specific way to make REST calls.

```
    import org.springframework.http.*;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    import java.util.Base64;

    public class Application {

        private static final String username = "user@domain.com";
        private static final String password = "password";
        private static final String jiraBaseURL = "https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/";
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;
        private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

        public Application() {
            restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            httpHeaders = createHeadersWithAuthentication();
        }

        private HttpHeaders createHeadersWithAuthentication() {
            String plainCreds = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCreds.getBytes());
            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

            return headers;
        }

        public ResponseEntity getIssue(String issueId) {
            String url = jiraBaseURL + "issue/" + issueId;

            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
            return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
        }

        public ResponseEntity createIssue(String key, String summary, String description, String issueType) {
            String createIssueJSON = createCreateIssueJSON(key, summary, description, issueType);

            String url = jiraBaseURL + "issue";

            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(createIssueJSON, httpHeaders);

            return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

        }

        private String createCreateIssueJSON(String key, String summary, String description, String issueType) {
            String createIssueJSON = "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"$KEY\"},\"summary\":\"$SUMMARY\",\"description\":\"$DESCRIPTION\",\"issuetype\": {\"name\": \"$ISSUETYPE\"}}}";

            createIssueJSON = createIssueJSON.replace("$KEY", key);
            createIssueJSON = createIssueJSON.replace("$SUMMARY", summary);
            createIssueJSON = createIssueJSON.replace("$DESCRIPTION", description);
            return createIssueJSON.replace("$ISSUETYPE", issueType);
        }

    }
```

For more details, you can read this blog post:
https://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/06/rest-api-calls-with-resttemplate.html

The full code is here:
https://github.com/somaiah/restTemplate